# Issue with saving checkbox value from form

Tags: python, django

I have looked at the other solutions on Stackoverflow but nothing seems to help with the problem I have.

I have an form for filling out information which needs to be saved.  I give the user three options which they can tick.  However, it won't save the form because it says the value isn't valid.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


FLAG_CHOICES = (('Active', 'Active'), ('Inactive', 'Inactive'), )
STATUS_CHOICES=(('Critical', 'Critical'), ('Medium', 'Medium'), ('Low','Low'))


class Event(models.Model):
    event_status=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    event_flag=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=FLAG_CHOICES)
    date_active=models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    time_active=models.TimeField(default=timezone.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_title
```

Here is my form:

```
from django import forms
from server_status.models import Event

FLAG_CHECKBOX = [('active', 'Active'), ('inactive', 'Inactive'), ]
STATUS_CHOICES=[('critical', 'Critical'), ('medium', 'Medium'), ('low','Low'),]


class Add_Event_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    event_title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Please enter an informative title.")
    event_status = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                             help_text="Please select the status of the event")
    event_description = forms.CharField(max_length=500, initial="",
                                        help_text="Enter a short description of the event here")
    event_flag = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=FLAG_CHECKBOX, required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                           help_text="Please select the status of this event.")
    date_active = forms.DateField(required=True, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
                                  help_text="Please select a date for this event.")
    time_active = forms.TimeField(required=True, widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%HH:%MM'),
                                  help_text="Please select a time for this event in HH:MM format.")


    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'  # I want all fields to be editable
```

This error displays on the webpage itself when you press Save:

```
Select a valid choice. [u'critical'] is not one of the available choices.
```

This error comes up when you tick the box that says 'Critical'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models you have the `STATUS_CHOICES`'s values(first value in each tuple) `Critical`, `Medium`, `Low` with first letter as upper case, but you did all lower cases in the form. You should modify the choices in models to use the same `STATUS_CHOICES` as the form one.